# R's algorithm for finding glm estimates

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multivariate-regression

Is there a way of seeing the algorithm behind the glm function in R? I'm not really interested in the source code, but the step by step algorithm for finding estimates for binomial family and how it was programmed in R.

Comment: Try typing `glm` into the console.

Comment: See `?glm`, it says "The default method "glm.fit" uses iteratively reweighted least squares (IWLS)"; as noted by @C11H17N2O2SNa you can check "how it was programmed in R" by looking at the source code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function  But there's so much fiddling around with error checks & such that @mdewy's suggestion is better if you want to know how the fundamental algorithm works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function uses iteratively weighted least squares. If you do not want to look at the source code for precise detail then perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model would help. An alternative would be

```
@BOOK{mccullagh83,
  author = {McCullagh, P and Nelder, J A},
  title = {Generalized linear models},
  year = 1983,
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall},
  address = {London},
   keywords= {glm}
}
```

or any other good book on GLMs which usually outline the fitting process for each of the common families and link functions.